# Mail bounces: SMTPUTF8 is required, but was not offered

Tags: postfix, smtp, utf-8

My mail server periodically sends out a newsletter to my clients. This is handled by a Perl script on the server. A few of the recipients names contain non-ASCII characters like ä, é, ö, etc. On my server, Postfix is setup with `smtputf8_enabled = yes` (or actually, the setting is omitted in main.cf since it defaults to 'yes'). For most of these clients, mail is delivered without a problem. But a few of the recipients' mail servers bounce my mails. My mail.info log file shows:

```
status=bounced (SMTPUTF8 is required, but was not offered by host ...
```

I've searched the interwebs and if I understand correctly, this is actually a problem at the receiving mail server, not the sending (my) mail server. But since I cannot change anything at the receiving end, and I still want those clients to receive my newsletter, what can I do at my end?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think your newsletter must be sent with another encoding. Perhaps ISO 8859-1. Did you find a solution?